# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = and table_name = migrations)

Tags: heroku, laravel-5

I am trying to run `heroku run php artisan migrate` and I get the error shown below. I have tried clearing config. I do not what the issue is.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from 
information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel 
and table_name = migrations)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had this same issue too. 
A couple of things might be wrong here.
1. Check all your parameters on your config setting on heroku to ensure they are correct[image]. You can connect to your db using sequel Pro to check that all your config variables are correct. In my case, I used Mysql so I had to use an add-on on heroku (cleardb)

2. Ensure that your .env file is not removed from your .gitignore. Which means .env is not supposed to be part of the commit. If your .env file is found in the repo too, there will be clash of which environment variables to use.

Answer (score 4):

change in your .env the DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to DB_HOST=localhost:8889

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

instead of

```
php artisan migrate
```

I also verified the connection data.
It worked because I already had some table on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue so this method works

```
DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
DB_PORT="3306"
DB_DATABASE="mydb"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=<enter your password"
```

this helped me in resolving this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).